# Spring security filter doesn't work. Spring bug?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I added to spring config my own custom filter:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").fullyAuthenticated();
}
```

but doFilter(...) doesn't invoke. I need to proccess request before it will be "eaten" by spring-security-oauth. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `addFilterBefore` configuration method "allows adding a filter before one of the known Filter classes. The known Filter instances are either a Filter listed in `HttpSecurityBuilder.addFilter(Filter)` or a Filter that has already been added using `HttpSecurityBuilder.addFilterAfter(Filter, Class)` or `HttpSecurityBuilder.addFilterBefore(Filter, Class)`"

[HttpSecurity documentaion](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilterBefore-javax.servlet.Filter-java.lang.Class-)

This basically means that your filter will be applied if and only if `BasicAuthenticationFilter` is already registered to process your requests, which is probably not.